# Issue understanding data request endpoint in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently studying an app that is used for logging a user in. And it mentions an endpoint under a function called request. Endpoint is than defined as `/login` what does this mean?

```
func request(endpoint: String,
                 parameters: [String: Any],
                 completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void)
```

Here is request being used in the app:

```
func formDataRequest(username: String, password: String) {
    let parameters = ["username": username,
                      "password": password]

    networkingService.request(endpoint: "/login", parameters: parameters) { [weak self] (result) in

        switch result {

        case .success(let user): self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: user)

        case.failure(let error):

            guard let alert = self?.alertService.alert(message: error.localizedDescription) else { return }
            self?.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Does /login refer to the header in HTTP

I just need to understand what the endpoint represents/means? Any ideas?

Comment: It would be the final part of the URL path - e.g. `https://some.server.com/login`

Comment: Oh of course, I can't believe I didn't think of that. I am having some trouble understanding why this xcode project is not able to correctly communicate with the api I created. Are you able to take a look at this project?

Comment: Have you run this project? You can try to put  a breakpoint inside `case .success` and `case . failure` in order to debug and see what's happening